# Поиск по диапазону в Mysql регистро независимый

Tags: регулярные-выражения, mysql-workbench

Выполняю следующий запрос:

SELECT * FROM patient where first_name REGEXP BINARY '^[а-я]';

В результате получаю имена, начинающиеся с заглавной буквы.
Проблема именно в диапазоне, если ищу по одной букве, например, '^[а]', то поиск регистрозависимый. Для диапазона значений - регистр не учитывается
Как найти имена, первая буква которых строчная?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: `SELECT * FROM patient WHERE SUBSTRING(first_name, 1, 1) REGEXP BINARY '[а-я]';`

Answer (score 0):

Если регэксп по строчным буквам отдаёт и прописные - значит, используется COLLATION без учёта регистра. Чтобы этого избежать, следует явно указать COLLATION для поля:

```
SELECT * 
FROM patient 
WHERE first_name COLLATE utf8mb4_bin REGEXP '^[а-я]';
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Допустимый COLLATION зависит от CHARSET поля. Получить список допустимых COLLATION можно запросом

```
SHOW COLLATION 
WHERE Charset = 'field charset';
```

Comment: Попробовала вот так 
SELECT * 
FROM patient 
WHERE binary first_name COLLATE utf8_bin  REGEXP '^[а-я]';
Результат все тот же...http://prntscr.com/muewk9

Comment: Запрос корректно работает с латинскими символами, с русскими - нет

Comment: @user329418 Какой charset/collation у: сервера, сессии, базы, таблицы, поля? ищите - косяк где-то тут.

Comment: у поля по которому происходит поиск COLLATION utf8_general_ci

Comment: Смотрите `show variables where variable_name rlike 'c(har|oll)';`.

Comment: для всех collatieon выставить utf8_bin?

Comment: @user329418 и поломать всё остальное? не, не нада... добавьте лучше вывод этого запроса в текст основного своего вопроса.